# How common is the short "be" in American English

Tags: pronunciation, american-english, british-english, north-american-english

A friend prompted me to look up the pronunciations of the homophones "[be](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/be)" (IPA: /bi/, /biː/) and "[bee](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/bee)" (IPA: /biː/). We found that there are two ways to say "be" -- one is short and the other (the strong form) is long (see this [OALD link](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/be)). Having lived in North America for almost a decade now, it seems to me that the long form is rare in North American usage, but that might just be me. My questions are:

1. Am I wrong?
2. If the short form is common in standard American usage, when would you it and when would you use the long form?

**EDIT:** Examples:

Long form:

1. **Edit:** <strike>I am He who said unto the world 'Be!' and it was.</strike>
2. "You'd better be there!".

Short form (at least in British English):
1. "I'll be there in a minute" when the speaker isn't trying to emphasize anything

Comment: I can't seem to come up with different pronunciations of 'be'. Can you give examples of sentences with one and the other pronunciation? (the noun 'bee' for the insect is -always- sounded 'long', though)

Comment: @Mitch: Please, see my recent edit.

Comment: This may be a problem of mine with not recognizing a distinction because I live with it (as an AmE speaker), but both your examples "You'd better be there" and "I'll be there in a minute" can have 'be; stressed or not, and the vowel articulation is the same. There's nothing special, long or short, here, just stress/accent. Asking which is more common is like asking how common is emphasis. (which could easily be less than non-emphasis, corroborating your experience. Also, your first sentence "Be and it was" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Mitch, here the context of the first sentence: "And the Word of YAHWEH said to Moses: "I am He who said unto the world 'Be!' and it was: and who in the future shall say to it 'Be!' and it shall be." ..." (Exodus 3:14, Jerusalem Targum) ... I'll update the question once again. Thanks.

Comment: @Mitch: I guess that's what it is ... stressed and unstressed.

Comment: A quotation from the Bible can hardly be used as an exemplar of English pronunciation. For one thing, it's not in English; and every English translation of it uses different words and grammar. For another thing, it's not spoken English and therefore has **no** pronunciation, standard or otherwise. It seems that Oxford is trying to emphasize the artificiality of certain Biblical pronunciations. In any event, nothing to worry about.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Point taken. I've struck out the biblical example.

Comment: Can you please supply IPA?

Comment: @tchrist: The IPA's are in the linked sites. I'll add them to the question. Thanks!

Comment: It could just be because I'm a Brit, but this question makes no sense to me as I'd pronounce all of the examples given here in exactly the same way.

Comment: The only example of 'be' using a longer vowel I can think of is from US sitcoms - "Could you be any more annoying?" with a stress on the "B" and a lengthened vowel. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the distinction between the phonemes /i/ and /iː/ is a British phenomenon; it doesn't exist in General American. In General American, the vowel /i/ may vary somewhat in length depending on how much stress you put on it, whether it's followed by a voiced or voiceless consonant, and other considerations, but it's all the same phoneme, and there is no sharp difference between /i/ and /iː/ the way you find in some British dialects.

In some British dialects, *Andy's* and *Andes* form a minimal pair distinguished mainly by the length of the vowel /i/—see the comments on [this entry](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2011/03/strong-and-weak.html) of John Wells' phonetic blog. This is not true for General American, and I suspect there are no American dialects where this happens.

Comment: I think you’re right. I think this is just a lengthening (or shortening) affect due to phrasal stress patterns. I don’t believe it to be phonemically distinct, because I don’t think there are minimal pairs. I don’t think of the vowels in *machine* and *happy* as different phonemes; just perhaps different allophones, if that.

Answer (score 3):

The strong form of the verb "be" and the noun "bee" are indeed homophones in standard BrE and AmE. They are both pronounced as /biː/ (The Cambridge English Pronouncing Dictionary - Roach, Hartman, and Setter  2006; The Longman Pronunciation Dictionary - Wells 2008). The Oxford Dictionary for Current English (Upton, Kretzschmar, and Konopka 2003) gives /bi/ for AmE.

Try saying *the **be** all and end all*  or *What'll it **be***? It might help.

For those who like playing with language, try saying the following words and pay attention to your vowels (which one is the longest/shortest?):

bee - bead - beet

You'll be surprised. :)